# How to check if a returned method in C# is an integer

Tags: c#, loops, methods, return-type

I would like to loop a method as long as the method does not return an integer in C#.

```
     public static int isAnInt()
    {
        rQuit = Console.ReadLine();
        if (Int32.TryParse(rQuit, out isQuit) == false)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Enter value again but as a number");
        }
        return isQuit;
    }
```

// Whilst inside the main method /

```
 while (int.TryParse(isAnInt() , out isQuit ) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This method is not an int try insert an int"); // For the method isAntInt I am trying to only
            //loop the method as 
            // long as it is not an integer.
        }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (that compiles).

Comment: Also, ask yourself why you have **two different** `int.TryParse` calls. And what `isAnInt` will return if the console input **is not** a number. If you can answer both of those two questions, you will realise the mistake you have made). _I am also surprised the code even compiles, but we'll put that to one side._

Comment: `isAnInt` is defined to return an `int`. It cannot return anything but an `int`.  So when you call `int.TryParse(isAnInt()...` you are trying to parse something that is already an `int`. You need to push your loop into the code that does the original parsing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("Type something");
        //It saves input
        int thenumber;
        //Check if Input is a number
        while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out thenumber))
        {//If input not a number then output this
            Console.WriteLine("Not a number");
        }
```

Here you go

Comment: Isn't `out var thenumber` better here?

Comment: No, why is that?

Comment: I have always used it this way

Comment: Because it's more concise (you don't repeat `int` and `thenumber`)